# What would be a standard framework, terminology, or procedure for extending function domains using isomorphisms?

Tags: metric-spaces, abstract-algebra

Suppose we have an isomorphism $h:A\rightarrow B$ between spaces $A$ and $B$.

*Remark: Alternatively, we may consider a isomorphism $h:X(0)\rightarrow X(t)$, where spaces $X(t)$ are parametrized by $t$, which may be time or some other process.*

There is a function defined on $A\times A$, let's say for definiteness that it is its metric $d:A\times A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Now, we want to extend the domain of this function $d$ to $A\cup B$, with extended function $\tilde{d}:(A\cup B)\times (A\cup B)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, using the isomorphism $h$:

$$
\tilde{d}\left(x,y\right):=\begin{cases}
d\left(x,y\right) & \forall x\in A\forall y\in A\\
d\left(x,h^{-1}\left(y\right)\right) & \forall x\in A\forall y\in B\\
d\left(h^{-1}\left(x\right),y\right) & \forall x\in B\forall y\in A\\
d\left(h^{-1}\left(x\right),h^{-1}\left(y\right)\right) & \forall x\in B\forall y\in B
\end{cases}
$$

Is there any standard framework, terminology, or procedure this would fall under, for the purpose of mathematical rigor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question has also been asked on MO: see the comment section there for some background. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182000/)

There are really two separate questions here.

1. Suppose we have an isomorphism $A \stackrel \sim \to B$ and some "extra structure" on $A$. Can we use the isomorphism to define the same kind of structure also on $B$?
2. Suppose we have some "extra structure" on both $A$ and $B$. Can we define the same kind of structure on the disjoint union $A \sqcup B$?

In short, the answer to 1. is always "yes" and the answer to 2. is "sometimes yes, sometimes no".

To elaborate on the first question, part of what mathematicians mean when they say that two things are isomorphic is that the two objects can be considered to actually be equal to each other (but possibly in many different, non-equivalent ways). But once you have fixed the choice of an isomorphism $A \stackrel \sim \to B$, it is more or less harmless to think of them as actually being equal. In particular,
any "structure" on $A$ -- a parametrization, a differential form, a group action, a stratification, a well-ordering, you name it -- automatically defines for you the same kind of structure on $B$. If I were writing for an audience comfortable with mathematical thinking I probably wouldn't even explicitly mention that I'm using "transport of structure".

To elaborate on the second question, just think about some simple examples. For instance, if I have a real-valued function on $A$ and one on $B$, then I can canonically define a real-valued function on $A \sqcup B$. But if I have two curves $\mathbb R \to A$, $\mathbb R \to B$, then I can't in any obvious way define a curve in $A \sqcup B$. (This is related to the "universal property" of $\sqcup$.) Some other things I can define on $A$ and $B$ separately to get something defined on the disjoint union: a vector bundle, a Riemannian metric, a vector field. In a way this does fall under a standard framework/terminolofy/procedure, namely that of *sheaf theory*, *gluing* and *descent*. But only in a slightly trivial way, because you're gluing only for disjoint unions, where you don't actually need to specify any gluing data.

But to relate to your example, there is no canonical metric on $A \sqcup B$ if $A$ and $B$ are metric spaces (although I could think of several ways to define one). If $A$ and $B$ are actually equal -- or if there is a chosen isomorphism between them, which amounts to the same thing by the first part -- then your proposal gives a well defined *pseudometric*. (This is what you get when you drop the axiom $d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y$ from the definition of a metric space.) More generally your proposed construction shows that any disjoint union of any number of copies of the same metric spaces has a natural pseudometric, whose metric identification is the metric space you started with. A slightly less cumbersome way to define it would be to say that $A \sqcup A = A \times \{0,1\}$ and then put
$$ \widetilde d((x_1,t_1),(x_2,t_2)) = d(x_1,x_2)$$
for $x_i \in A$, $t_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer, as well as for exceptionally following this question from MO to math.SE. I suppose that I did not formulate the question in an optimal way. I am familiar with the subject matter at a level, which is adequate for my qualification of Master's in Mathematics, and in particular, I know that the "Can we" questions you listed have a positive answer, subject to certain conditions for the second one. However, your answer may be exactly what I was looking for. You gave pointers on framework/terminology/procedure and discussed the topic in a more rigorous way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy it could be helpful.